# How can I get access to service variables?

Tags: php, symfony, scope

```
public function pages($slug, PagesGenerator $pagesGenerator)
{
    $output = $pagesGenerator->getPages($slug);

    $id = $page->getId();

    return $this->render('list.html.twig', [ 'output' => $output,  'id' => $id]);
}
```

But I get the error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: page

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$output['page']->getId()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function pages($slug, PagesGenerator $pagesGenerator)
{
    $output = $pagesGenerator->getPages($slug);

    // here is your error: $page is not defined.
    $id = $page->getId();

    // something like this?
    $id = $output['page']->getId();

    return $this->render('list.html.twig', [ 'output' => $output,  'id' => $id]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your new controller obviously have not `template` variable into list of variables, just `output`. Looks like your correct code should be:

```
  public function pages($slug, PagesGenerator $pagesGenerator)
  {
      $output = $pagesGenerator->getPages($slug);

      return $this->render('list.html.twig', $output);
  }
```

**UPDATE**: Answer for updated question is basically the same, all you need to do is to either pass your template variable as plain array

```
return $this->render('list.html.twig', array_merge($output, ['table' => $table]));
```

or use them accordingly to their actual structure in template, e.g. `{{ output.page }}` instead of `{{ page }}`

Comment: Thank you. I updated my question to show you, that my case is a little bit more difficult. I also want to be able to have access inside the controller to "page"

Comment: So I still get the error message `Notice: Undefined variable: page`

Comment: @Jarla I've updated answer, but is is not a good practice to change question after answer have been published. Consider publishing correct questions from the start

Comment: Yes, sorry. I just realized, the update is more clear